# Path variables in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/post/:post_id', component: PostComponent }
])
```

Using this classic route strategy `/post/1715` I received this JSON data.

```
{
  "post_id": 1715,
  "title": "The Post Title",
  "urlTitle": "the-post-title",
  "body": "Blah, blah ... blah"
}
```

But how to redirect router to Stackoverflow URL style `/post/1715/the-post-title` by adding `urlTitle` to the link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@RouteConfig([
        { path: 'post/:id',   component: PostRedirect },
        { path: 'post/:id/:title', component: PostComponent }
])
```

The first component reads the id and then redirects to the second one with the title.

complete sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/5BSzvpOH2kAfPAUnJj4O?p=preview